# Unable to distribute due to App Store Connect Operation Error

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am using Share extension in my project. It was successful when I distributed the same project with a share extension last time. But currently, I am getting ERROR ITMS-90359 and ERROR ITMS-90357.

Please help if anybody has[image] a workaround for this issue.

Comment: From the text, I would look if you have moved the location of the storyboard, and eventually change the information about it in the info.plist file. Additionally I would look if an NSExtensionPrincipalClass is defined there and if that makes sence?

Comment: I have not moved the storyboard location and NSExtensionPrincipalClass not defined in the info.plist. Info.plist has only NSExtensionMainStoryboard key and value as "MainInterface".

Comment: Then I have no Idea. If no one can help you with that here I recommend you to ask apple developer support directly. If I remember right, when you have a developer subscription, you get free help for a problem for two times?